# Any way to simulate numpad input on MacBook Air 2011?

Tags: mac, vmware-fusion, numpad

I'm, running a 747 simulator in VMware Fusion on a mid-2011 MacBook Air. It *requires* the use of the numpad (its very old) to enter numbers into the CDU. I have tried FN+keys on the right side of the keyboard even though they are not printed on the keys and of course it didn't work.

Is there any way to do this without external peripherals, as the solution must be completely mobile and usable on the run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Macworld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1142609/ressurect_numberpad.html), installing [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html) and rebooting your Mac will give you the ability to use Fn+keys as a numpad.